# Python list to dictionary in python, with selected list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list with special character # which is subgrouped I wanted to make dictionary from the list with the subgroup.

```
list1 = ['#model1','path1','path2','path4','path5','#model2','path12'
            'path13','#model3','path4','path6']

## Just wanted to make dictionary such that whenever I see a string with # sign
## untill the next # sign here  #model2 that is in dictionary entry
##(model1,('path1','path2','path4','path5')) and so on...

def get_me_hash_index(my_list):
    index = [idx for idx,x in enumerate(my_list) if x.strip().find('#')!=-1]

    return index

def get_new_dict(my_list,hash_position):
    return {my_list[hash_position[idx-1]]:my_list[hash_position[idx-1]+1:hash_position[idx]] for idx in range(len(hash_position))}


hash_pos = get_me_hash_index(list1)
new_dict = get_new_dict(list1,hash_pos)
print hash_pos
print new_dict
```

result is :

```
[0, 5, 7]
{'#model1': ['path1', 'path2', 'path4', 'path5'], '#model3': [], '#model2': ['path12path13']}
```

somehow not working for model3 and model2.

Comment: I don't quite understand the structure. Can you describe it a little bit better?

Comment: Its a list [first_three,a,b,c,second_three,d,e,f....,last_three,x,y,z] just wanted to make first_three:(a,b,c) second_three:(d,e,f) ..so on..using dictionary.. hope it makes little clear..

Comment: @wooble i was not expecting the code but some ideas, the way I wrote the question was confusing to you guys, I have posted part of code that I worked on.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your first problem is that you're missing a comma on the first line, so your list contains "path12path13".

But your dict comprehension is also off a bit. It's best to not to try to cram everything into one line; something like this works:

```
def get_new_dict(my_list):
    rv = {}
    key = None
    vals = []
    for item in my_list:
        if item.startswith('#'):
            if key is not None:
                rv[key] = vals
                vals = []
            key = item
        else:
            vals.append(item)
    rv[key] = vals
    return rv

list1 = ['#model1','path1','path2','path4','path5','#model2','path12',
         'path13','#model3','path4','path6']

print get_new_dict(list1)
```

Comment: It works pretty good. Thanks for the answer appreciated, it is completely different approach than what I was thinking. Sorry for my initial questioning approach which caused confusion. Thanks again.